# Can we provide JSP pages from sec/main/resources source folder

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to provide JSP pages under sec/main/resources instead of webapp folder and configured source folder in application.properties as below but not working, let me know can we do this and how

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/src/main/resources
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp